# Chromium is showing a wrong path to the Desktop

Tags: chromium, paths

I just installed chromium from the Ubuntu Software center, and when I try to download anything and choose the Desktop link from the left column located on that window that appears, it saves the document into a wrong Desktop folder, like "home/user/snap/chromium/538/Desktop", for example.

And this happens to the other links, like Documents, Downloads, Images and so on.

[image]

Note the real desktop has some files, but the chromium one is empty.

How can I make that link point to the right path (home/user/Desktop)?

Comment: Please explain how you downloaded and installed chromium. I guess it's a snap ?

Comment: I installed it through the Ubuntu Software app. I'm not sure if I know what a snap is. I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: Have you tried changing settings under Advance setting->Downloads->Location?

Comment: @Kulfy I can change the downloads location, but I have issues with the links at the left column of the dialog. All those links point to a wrong folder.

Comment: It might be helpful if you can post a screenshot of dialogue

Comment: @Kulfy Sure. I've updated the question.

Comment: @darksoulsong I've updated my answer. If it helps upvote and mark it as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialogue shows the location set under ***Advance settings→Downloads→Location***. For e.g. if path is:

[image: Example 1(1)]

then dialogue shows

[image: Example 1(2)]

So, change the path in Location to get dialogue in desired folder.

In my case Chromium installed via snap (Software Center) is unable to read the contents of `/home/username/Desktop` although it can download and save files to that folder. I am getting error as *Permission denied*. I'm digging up the cause and reporting to Google. I believe this is a bug. The error is just read error and Chromium is still able to write the content.

#### Update:

This is a bug under Chromium distributed by snap. I tried reinstalling but results are same. On the other hand, I tried Chromium installation by apt and that Chromium is working fine without any error.

Comment: Kulfy, thanks for your answer. I know how to change the location of the downloads folder, I wish I could be able to do the same to those links in the upper part of the left column of the dialog. This is the real problem.

Anyway, I'm going to reinstall it like you did, that is, using apt this time. Thanks for the idea.